# Why does the "Try a higher/lower number." only appear after the second run?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

When I run the code with the commented out portion, the program works as intended. After the first guess, it tells the user to try a higher or lower number. Without the commented out portion, the prompts only appear after the second guess.

I just started learning Java and the book I am following does not offer further explanation.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessAgain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numGuesses = 0;
        int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;


        int minbound = 1;
        int maxbound = 100;

        out.println("          **********          ");
        out.println(" Welcome to the Guessing Game ");
        out.println("          **********          ");
        out.println();

        out.print(" Enter an number from " + minbound + " to " + maxbound + ": ");
        int inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        numGuesses++;

        /*
        if (inputNumber > randomNumber) {
            out.println("Try a lower number!");
        }
        if (inputNumber < randomNumber) {
            out.println("Try a higher number!");

         */

            while (inputNumber != randomNumber) {
                out.println();
                out.print(" Enter an number from " + minbound + " to " + maxbound + ": ");
                inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
                numGuesses++;

                if (inputNumber > randomNumber) {
                    out.println("Try a lower number!");
                }
                if (inputNumber < randomNumber) {
                    out.println("Try a higher number!");
                }
            }

            out.println("You win after " + numGuesses + " guesses.");

            keyboard.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I mean, there's no reason it would be printed first. It comes after the `out.println...numGuesses++;` part inside the while loop, so it makes sense that "Try a lower number" will only be printed after you've taken 1 piece of input, gone into the while loop, and taken another piece of input

Comment: I would suggest a do-while loop (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Without the commented code, you go directly to the while loop which asks for input, instead of processing the previous one. You should instead let the while loop ask for all the inputs, including the first one.

Comment: Try using do while , instead of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because after the first guess you are entering the while loop, which starts with asking for a new guess before giving a hint.

First ask is outside of while loop, second is inside, afterwards comes the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print out the result before asking for the next input.
For example:

```
while (inputNumber != randomNumber) {
    if (inputNumber > randomNumber) out.println("Try a lower number!");
    if (inputNumber < randomNumber) out.println("Try a higher number!");

    out.println();
    out.print(" Enter an number from " + minbound + " to " + maxbound + ": ");
    inputNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
    numGuesses++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! Can you please provide some more information about why your solution fixes the stated problem?

Comment: The system is waiting for two inputs, so before asking the user to enter the second value, the system needs to print the result for the first value. This can be achieved by putting the output in front of the scanner, who is waiting for the next input.